# Can you do an offline installation of IBM Cloud Private Community Edition (ICP CE)?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Can you do an offline installation of IBM Cloud Private Community Edition (ICP CE)?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @K. Alexander brought some good points.  I made some changes to the script itself and modified it to work for my own personal use.

[Create offline package for icp ce](https://github.com/AKx2f/icp/blob/master/create_offline_package_ce.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are only valid for 1.2. Offline installation instructions for IBM Cloud Private-CE will not be published for 2.1.